# Should I prove $S_{N + k} \geq S_{N + i} \forall N, i = 0, 1, 2, \dots, k$ and $k \geq i$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, induction

Here is the question I am trying to prove:

Suppose $a_n > 0$ for each $n$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges. Let $s_n = a_1 + \dots + a_n.$

$(a)$ Prove that $$\frac{a_{N+1}}{S_{N + 1}} + \frac{a_{N+2}}{S_{N + 2}} + \dots + \frac{a_{N+k}}{S_{N + k}} \geq 1 - \frac{S_N}{S_{N + k}} \quad \quad \forall N \geq 1, k \geq 1.$$

My questions are:

1-Is my statement $S_{N + k} \geq S_{N + i} \quad \forall N, i = 0, 1, 2, \dots, k$ and  $k \geq i$ actually correct?

2-Should I prove $S_{N + k} \geq S_{N + i} \quad \forall N, i = 0, 1, 2, \dots, k$ and  $k \geq i$ during my proof (I think by induction)of the required ?

Comment: I guess you mean $s=S$. Then the positivity of $a_n$ guarantees you the inequality in the title immediately. But this is only a small step toward proving (a), I would say.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim yes u are absolutely correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment said, you get $S_k\geq S_i$ for all $i\leq k$ immediately from the fact that $a_n>0$, as $S_k = S_i + a_{i+1}+a_{i+2}+\dots+a_k$. Using this, we can calculate
$$ 1-\frac{S_N}{S_{N+k}} = \frac{S_{N+k}}{S_{N+k}}-\frac{S_N}{S_{N+k}} = \frac{a_{N+1}+a_{N+2}+\dots+a_{N+k}}{S_{N+k}} $$
$$ = \frac{a_{N+1}}{S_{N+k}}+\frac{a_{N+2}}{S_{N+k}}+\dots + \frac{a_{N+k}}{S_{N+k}}\leq \frac{a_{N+1}}{S_{N+1}}+\frac{a_{N+2}}{S_{N+2}}\dots + \frac{a_{N+k}}{S_{N+k}}$$
as desired. Note that we used your inequality for the last step.

Comment: But this does not answer my questions I think or at least does not give me a direct answer

Comment: But I am asking about my statement not yours

Comment: Okay, I may have jumped the gun then. To answer as directly as possible: 
1. Yes, it is true.
2. Yes, you should prove it, but do not give a more detailed argument than I gave at the beginning of my answer, anything more is unnecessary. You should not do it by induction.